# Tell me... What am I?

Tags: riddle

I'm far to the left, and also the right, but not to either side.
I float in water, not in air, yet rest in levitation.
I am just one when multiple, and disappear when alone.
What am I?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Is it

> The Letter t

Explanation

line 1

> Exists in left and right

line 2

> exists in water and levitation but not air

line 3

> exists in multiple but not in alone.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Political Parties?

I'm far to the left, and also the right, but not to either side.

> Liberals are considered to be left, conservatives right, but in reality they are not defined by literal sides

I float in water, not in air, yet rest in levitation.

> Sorry, not sure... resting in levitation could be a jab at politicians never getting anywhere?

I am just one when multiple, and disappear when alone.

> If there are multiple politicians with the same views they are one party. If there is only one politician, they cannot be a party